# Laravel, how can I show the name field via foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the User model and Consulta model, the consulta model have foreign key 'user_id' references id on user.

sorry for my English.

I need to show on user_id the user name in my list

Model  User

```
public function consultas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Consulta','user_id');
}
```

Model Consulta

```
public function usuarios()
{
return $this->hasMany('User');
}
```

Controller, only '$registros' it works

```
$userteste = User::with('consultas')->get();
$registros = Consulta::all();
return view('consultas.index' , compact('registros','userteste'));
```

And view

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Data</th>
<th>Hora</th>
<th>Situação</th>
<th>Ação</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($registros as $registro)
@can('ver-consulta', $registro)
<tr>        
<td>{{$registro -> user_id}} </td>  
<td>{{$registro -> data}} </td> 
<td>{{$registro -> hora}}</td>  
<td>{{$registro -> situacao}} </td>
<td>
<a class="btn teal" href="/consultas/editar/{{$registro->id}}">
<i class="material-icons">local_printshop</i>
</a>                
</td>
</tr>
@endcan
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need in 'user_id' show the 'name' on table user, not number off id.
sorry for my English

```
in this case the results
nome = 1
I need in 'Nome' the name of user:
nome = luiz
```

Answer (score 1):

La relación en el modelo Consulta tiene que ser:

```
public function usuario()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}
```

En el controller podes hacer:

```
$registros = Consulta::with('usuario')->get();
```

Y en la vista:

```
@foreach($registros as $registro)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $registro->usuario->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Es recomendable chequear si existe la relación antes de acceder a la propiedad:

```
{{ !is_null($registro->usuario) ? $registro->usuario->name : 'No user assigned' }}
```

Comment: Class 'User' not found, i try Use App\User; on Consulta model but not works

Comment: @LuizFelipeBurgattJolo try like `return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');`

Answer (score 0):

In case the `Consulta` belongs to the `User`

```
// In Model Consulta
public function usuarios()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

// Controller
$registros = Consulta::with('usuarios')->get();

// View
<td>{{ $registro->usuarios->nome }}</td>
```

Comment: @LuizFelipeBurgattJolo You are right. Sorry, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

**User Model**

```
public function consultas()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Consulta');
 }
```

**Model Consulta**

```
public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
  }
```

**Controller**

```
$registros = Consulta::all();
```

**View**

```
@foreach(registros as registro)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $registro->user->name }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```